Windows 10 + MiniConda + Spyder + TensorFlow. How to make them work together?
What softwares do I have?

Windows 10 22H2 19045.4894;
Miniconda3 py312_24.7.1-0 (Python 3.12.4 64-bit);
Spyder standalone 6.0.0.

What software do I need?

TensorFlow.

Question:
How do I make a Conda environment on Windows 10 that can accomodate both tensorflow and spyder-kernels=3.0 at the same time?
What have I tried so far?
First attempt at creating the environment:
I've tried conda create -n tf tensorflow spyder spyder-kernels. This has led to the following packages being installed, according to conda list:

python Version: 3.7.12 Build: h900ac77_100_cpython Channel: conda-forge;
spyder Version: 5.3.3 Build: py37h03978a9_0 Channel: conda-forge;
spyder-kernels Version: 2.3.3 Build: py37h03978a9_0 Channel: conda-forge;
tensorflow Version: 1.14.0 Build: h1f41ff6_0 Channel: conda-forge.

This does not satisfies Spyder 6.0.0 requirements. When I open it, I get an error in the Console of the IDE:

An error occurred while starting the kernel
The Python environment or installation whose interpreter is located at
C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\tf\python.exe

doesn't have spyder‑kernels version >=3.0.0,<3.1.0 installed. Without this module
and specific version is not possible for Spyder to create a console
for you.
You can install it by activating your environment (if necessary) and then running in a system terminal:
conda install spyder-kernels=3.0

or
pip install spyder-kernels==3.0.*


Doing as suggested does not solves my problem. Instead, it throws me inside a DEPENDENCY HELL:
conda install spyder-kernels=3.0
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides _python_rc needed by python-3.12.0rc3-rc3_h2628c8c_1_cpython

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.7.* , which can be installed;
└─ spyder-kernels 3.0**  is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ spyder-kernels 3.0.0 would require
   │  └─ python >=3.8  but there are no viable options
   │     ├─ python [3.10.0|3.10.1|...|3.9.9] conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │     └─ python [3.12.0rc3|3.13.0rc1|3.13.0rc2] would require
   │        └─ _python_rc, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
   └─ spyder-kernels 3.0.0 would require
      └─ __unix, which is missing on the system.

I've seached SuperUser for an answer to my problem but have not found any solution.
Doing as suggested by Ramhound, that is, conda install python=3.8, only made the DEPENDENCY HELL much bigger.

You need to update your Python to 3.8 in order to fully configure out environment the way you want.

You don’t need to comment, you need to edit your question as appropriate, to include the current state of your Python environment. Helps if you adjust your tone, not to make it sound like, installing what is required to configure your system the way you want is a pain.

@Ramhound Sorry, I was not intending to have a wrong tone. But I don't see a need to edit the question, since I found a solution and offered it as an answer.

A wrong version by large: tensorflow=1.14.0.
It ideally should be tensorflow=2.17.0.
So, instead of:

conda create -n tf tensorflow spyder spyder-kernels

do:

conda create -n tf2 tensorflow=2 spyder spyder-kernels=3.0.0

This will install:

tensorflow Version: 2.10.0 Build: mkl_py310hd99672f_0

